# Write shorthand notation for margin using theme object for styling with jss using material-ui

Tags: css, material-ui, jss

I am able to style the component by applying the margin in the following way.

**style.js**

```
const styles = theme => ({
    button: {
    margin: '12px 18px',
    }
})
```

**But I want to use material-ui's `theme.spacing.unit` to apply the margin to the component. I did it as follows:**

**style.js**

```
const styles = theme => ({
    button: {
    margin: '`${theme.spacing.unit * 3}` `${theme.spacing.unit * 4}`',
    }
})
```

But I am not having any luck on this. Can someone point out my mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the unit:

```
const styles = theme => ({
    button: {
        margin: `${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 4}px`,
    }
})
```